# sedの引数を変数に格納する方法

Tags: bash, shellscript, sed

例えば、次のコマンド

```
echo a b c d e f | sed -e 's/.*\(b.*e\).*/\1/' -e 's/.*b c *\(.*\) .*/\1/'
```

の`-e 's/.*\(b.*e\).*/\1/' -e 's/.*b c *\(.*\) .*/\1/'`の部分を変数に格納して

```
echo a b c d e f | sed ${regex[0]}
```

のように実行したいのですが、変数が展開されるときにクォーテーションマークがどのように付与されるのかを理解できず、

```
regex[0]='-e s/.*\(b.*e\).*/\1/'
```

まではできたのですが、コマンドにスペースが入った場合、どうすれば良いのかわからないため、後半のコマンドを格納することができません。
この場合、どのように変数に格納すれば良いのでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: s コマンドを一つにまとめてみてはどうでしょう。`regex='-e s/.*\(b.*e\).*/\1/;s/.*b c *\(.*\) .*/\1/';echo a b c d e f | sed "$regex"`

Comment: ご回答いただきまして、ありがとうございます。なるほど！確かにこのようにすれば`-e`が不要になり問題なく実行できますね。しかし、`-e`が2つ以上あるとうまく実行できない原因と、それ自体への解決方法がわからないので、モヤモヤします^^;

Comment: `regex='-e s/.*\(b.*e\).*/\1/ -e s/.*b c *\(.*\) .*/\1/'` としてしまうと、全体が一つの文字列引数として sed に渡されてしまうためです。2個目の `-e` 以降のコマンド(ここでは ` -e s/.*b c *\\(.*\\) .*/\1/` の部分)が、最初の `s` コマンドの一部として扱われることになります。そのため、`echo ...|sed "$regex"` を実行すると、`unknown option to \`s'` というエラーメッセージが表示されるはずです。

Comment: `sed`の`s`コマンドが原因なんですね。それでは、エスケープすることはできないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

みなさんご回答いただきまして、ありがとうございました。
今回は最も簡素で意図していた形に近いmetropolisさんの`-e`を一つにまとめる回答を採用させていただきたいと思います。

```
regex='-e s/.*\(b.*e\).*/\1/;s/.*b c *\(.*\) .*/\1/'
echo a b c d e f | sed "$regex"
```

今後場合によっては`eval`を利用する必要があるかもしれません。頭の隅に入れさせていただきます。

Answer (score 1):

若干regex変数の定義がお望みのものと違うかもしれませんが以下は如何でしょうか。

```
regex="sed -e 's/.*\(b.*e\).*/\1/' -e 's/.*b c *\(.*\) .*/\1/'"
echo a b c d e f |eval ${regex}
```

Comment: ご回答いただきまして、ありがとうございます。なるほど。確かにevalを使えば元の書式のまま変数に格納できますね。

Answer (score 0):

引数部分を分けてみました。

```
declare -A array["r"]="-e 's/.*\(b.*e\).*/\1/' -e 's/.*b c *\(.*\) .*/\1/'"
c="sed ${array["r"]}"
echo a b c d e f | eval $c
```

Comment: declare や eval を使わずに `regex=('-e s/.*\(b.*e\).*/\1/' '-e s/.*b c *\(.*\) .*/\1/');echo a b c d e f | sed "${regex[@]}"` としても良いかな、と。

Comment: 質問にある引数の形の優先度を上げてしまいました。アドバイス有難うございます。

Comment: @Tanaike ご回答いただきまして、ありがとうございます。変数を複数用意すれば、確かに質問の通りの内容を実現できますね。

Comment: @metropolis ご回答いただきまして、ありがとうございます。もともとregexは配列を使ってループを回す予定で、説明を簡単にするために、変数で質問しました。なので、今回ご回答いただいたような形で配列を利用することはできません。

Answer (score 0):

オフトピっぽいですが`-f`を使うとそもそも変数を使わずに済みます。

```
printf 's/.*\(b.*e\).*/\\1/\n' > hoge.sed
printf 's/.*b c *\(.*\) .*/\\1/\n' >> hoge.sed
echo a b c d e f  | sed -f hoge.sed
```